# CSS - Style svg fill with class name

Tags: css, svg, fill

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/morettmt/v7mx737w/2/

I can chnage the fill color by styling the grouping

Is there a way to add my own class to the svg and use that in my css

```
    .triangle{
        fill: red;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `.triangle g` as the selector? The inner `g` has a different fill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have the class in the SVG you'll have to do something like this

```css
.play-triangle>g {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="play-triangle" width="100px" height="107px" viewBox="0 0 10 17" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
  <g id="Guide" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Iconography" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-421.000000, -286.000000)">
      <path d="M421.002864,301.137442 C421.001935,301.394293 421.098144,301.651636 421.293405,301.846897 C421.686652,302.240144 422.317878,302.236638 422.709368,301.845148 L429.778687,294.775829 L430.485793,294.068722 L422.709368,286.292297 C422.322784,285.905713 421.68393,285.900024 421.293405,286.290548 C421.086336,286.497617 420.989274,286.77067 421.000938,287.039961 C421.000655,287.049803 421.000512,287.059682 421.000512,287.069594 L421.000512,301.067851 C421.000512,301.091254 421.001305,301.114459 421.002864,301.137442 L421.002864,301.137442 L421.002864,301.137442 Z"
        id="Rectangle-78" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the colour from your `class` style, was being over-ridden by the explicit `fill` you had on the child `<g>` element.  If you remove that, your CSS works.

```css
.triangle{
 fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100px" height="107px" viewBox="0 0 10 17" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
     
     <g class="triangle" id="Guide" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
         <g id="Iconography" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-421.000000, -286.000000)">
             <path d="M421.002864,301.137442 C421.001935,301.394293 421.098144,301.651636 421.293405,301.846897 C421.686652,302.240144 422.317878,302.236638 422.709368,301.845148 L429.778687,294.775829 L430.485793,294.068722 L422.709368,286.292297 C422.322784,285.905713 421.68393,285.900024 421.293405,286.290548 C421.086336,286.497617 420.989274,286.77067 421.000938,287.039961 C421.000655,287.049803 421.000512,287.059682 421.000512,287.069594 L421.000512,301.067851 C421.000512,301.091254 421.001305,301.114459 421.002864,301.137442 L421.002864,301.137442 L421.002864,301.137442 Z" id="Rectangle-78" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
         </g>
     </g>
 </svg>
```